# Proving that a zero Wronskian implies linear dependence without Abel's theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

**Claim:** If the Wronskian of $x_1,\dots x_n$ is zero and $L(x_i)=0, \quad i=1,\dots,n$, where $L$ is a linear differential operator or order $n$, with continuous coefficients, then $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is not a fundamental set of solutions.

**Proof:** If the Wronskian $W(t)=0$ for some $t$, then for some non-zero vector $a$ and for $x=\sum a_ix_i$ we have $x_i(t)=x'(t)=\dots x^{(n-1)}(t)=0$, therefore by uniqueness of the solution $x\equiv0$, hence $x_1,\dots x_n$ is not a fundamental set of solutions. q.e.d.

Is this not a sound proof?

Comment: The title and claim are at odds. Your proof establishes the title, but the claim is incorrect.

Comment: Wrong claim, I meant to write "not a fundamental..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof seems to say that if $$y(t_0) = y'(t_0) = \cdots = y^{(n-1)}(t_0)=0$$ for some $t_0$ then $y(t) = 0$ for all $t$. However given the linear differential equation: $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} y = 1$$ we have a solution $y=x^{n}/n!$ that satisfies this, yet it is not identically zero.